# Adding and deleting canvases by clicking buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a comic-making web-application and I need to allow support for multiple canvases or "panels" as we put it. I want to be able to **create**/**delete** and if possible, **duplicate** canvases by clicking on their corresponding buttons. E.g, add canvas button adds a canvas, delete deletes a panel etc.

```html
<button onclick='addPanel()'>Add another canvas</button>
```

```js
addPanel() {
  // ...
}
```

I'm currently using **Canvas** and **FabricJS** but I'm willing to use a new library if it will help me achieve this.

You can get a better understanding of what I'm after with [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuAyj.png).

Comment: Well it's actually matter of creating an element from dom so check the API's from mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement also look remove same. And duplicating also included this situation =)

Comment: Will that work with Fabricjs though? With Fabricjs, you need to do `var c = new fabric.Canvas('c', {}` to create a canvas.

Comment: Well inside of that code I'm sure it's also using `createElement`. You might figure it out looking up it's own docs. Could be pass it with options?

Comment: I think people would've helped if you had shown more effort into this. For example, show what you already tried, or a boilerplate code that you worked on top of.

Comment: It is a general question and my question perfectly sums up what I'm after. I don't have any relevant code to include because once again, this is a question and not a problem with my code. @ConstantinTeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your question.

I know we can optimize it using only jQuery. Please do it.

```js
var canvas = null; 
var CANVAS_LIST = {}; 
var pageId =0; 

function addPanels(el){
console.log(el.value); 
 for(let i = 0 ; i<el.value; i++){
  pageId= pageId+1; 
  addPage(pageId); 
 }
}

function copyPage(srcPageId){
pageId = pageId+1;
 addPage(pageId)
 CANVAS_LIST[pageId].clear(); 
 
  CANVAS_LIST[pageId].loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify( CANVAS_LIST[srcPageId]), function(){ CANVAS_LIST[pageId].renderAll()});
 
 CANVAS_LIST[pageId].renderAll(); 
}

function addPage(pageId){

var rmvButton = document.createElement("button"); 
  var div = document.createElement("div"); 
  div.id = "div_"+pageId; 

   var t = document.createTextNode("Remove");
  rmvButton.setAttribute("style","color:red;font-size:23px");
  rmvButton.appendChild(t);
  rmvButton.id = "btn_"+pageId;
  rmvButton.onclick = function () {
    let id = $(this).attr("id").replace('btn_',''); 
    CANVAS_LIST[id].dispose();
    $("#div_"+id).remove(); 
  }


var copybtn = document.createElement("button"); 
   t = document.createTextNode("Copy");
  copybtn.setAttribute("style","color:green;font-size:23px");
  copybtn.appendChild(t);
  copybtn.id = "btn_copy_"+pageId;
  copybtn.onclick = function () {
  let id = $(this).attr("id").replace('btn_copy_',''); 

  copyPage(id); 
}

  var canElement = document.createElement("canvas"); 
  canElement.width = 200; 
  canElement.height = 200; 
  canElement.id = "can_"+pageId;
  div.append(copybtn);
  div.append(rmvButton);
  div.append(canElement);
  
  $("#panel").append(div); 
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canElement);
  canvas.id ="can_"+pageId;
  CANVAS_LIST[pageId] =canvas; 

  selectedCanvas = CANVAS_LIST[pageId]; 
  selectedCanvas.add(new fabric.IText("Page "+pageId));
  selectedCanvas.renderAll();
}

$("#addPage").click(function(){
  pageId= pageId+1; 
  addPage(pageId); 
});
```

```css
canvas{
border: black solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text" value="" placeholder="How many panels you want?" id="panelInput" onBlur="addPanels(this)"> 

<hr/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Add Page" id="addPage"> 

<div id="panel">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

This is a basic of JavaScript:

```js
    var x= "1";
    function add_canvas(){
        var add_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        document.body.appendChild(add_canvas);
        add_canvas.setAttribute("id", "mycanvas_"+ x );
        add_canvas.setAttribute("class", "canvas");
        color();
    }
    function remove_canvas(){
        x--;
        var remove_canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas_"+x);
        remove_canvas.remove();
    }
    function color(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas_"+x);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
        x++;
    }
```

```html
    <button onclick="add_canvas()">ADD CANVAS</button>
    <button onclick="remove_canvas()">REMOVE CANVAS</button>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this but with a FabricJS canvas instead of the basic canvases?